# UserProfile state persistent between users in bot v4

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

When I have two instances of the bot (can be two emulator windows or two browsers if I deploy the bot to Azure), the first name enter is persistent for all the other instances.

Instance One

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPw7.jpg

Instance Two

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J21bC.jpg

I would expect the bot ask my name again, it does not matter how many instances I have, the bot always identifies me as Brunno. How can I change this behavior?

I followed [this tutorial](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/1032/Using-Dialogs-MS-Bot-Framework-V4-Preview-Edition)

Comment: Are you using the same UserId in both instances?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by opening a web browser? Are you using Test in WebChat in Azure, or did you configure WebChat to work on your own web page? Also, in the emulator, have you tried opening the restart conversation drop down menu and restarting the conversation with a new user id? Typically, data will persist between conversations if both conversation windows are using the same user id.

Comment: @stuartd, I did a test and in both instances have the some UserId
Instance 1:
  "from": {
    "id": "42f4df72-06c1-406a-b144-95b0b908c379",
    "name": "User"
  },
Instance 2:
"from": {
    "id": "42f4df72-06c1-406a-b144-95b0b908c379",
    "name": "User"
  },
How can I fix it? How I can create a new user id for every new instance?

Comment: hi @tdurnford, I meant have two browser at the same time, Firefox and Chrome.
I configure the WebChat to work on my own page.
Restart conversation (Restart with new user ID) solved the problem in the emulator. How can I fix this issue in the Webchat to work on my own page? How can I make sure that every user has a new User id? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide WebChat with a unique id for each conversation, it will reference the same data objects in storage. So to the resolve this issue, you should generate a random id for each user or conversation instance. See the code snippet below for an example.

```
const userID = Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36);

...

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
store,
userID
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Also check latest README.md of webchat [WEBCHAT API reference](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#web-chat-api-reference)
It states

> If userID is not specified, it will default to a random user ID

Might be more efficient.