# Where/when does a bot make a new conversation for each user

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

This is a more general question of how bots work more then a specific coding question but bear with me.

With my current bot when a users first enters a page on a website all of their answers are filtered by "king-kingvalue", then if they go to another page it will change to "queen-queenvalue". The problem is that if UserA is on the page that sets their filter to "queen-queenvalue", and then UserB goes to the page with the "king-kingvalue" filter, UserA's filters are also set to "king-kingvalue".

So, my question is where/when are separate conversations for each user being established within the code?
From my understanding the bot.. 
-->gets the filter from the website and passes it to the BotController, where the PostAsync is called.

```
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly IBot _bot;

        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
        }
```

-->Makes a new instance of the Bot, which in turn creates a new Conversation and User State.

```
    public class QnABot : DialogBot<QnADialog>
    {
        public QnABot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, IQnAService qnaService, ILogger<QnABot> logger)
             : base(conversationState, userState, new QnADialog(qnaService), logger)
        {

        }
```

-->And at this point each new user should have their own unique conversation with the bot, yes?

However, this does not seem to be the case for me because code that edits and saves the Conversation and User States will effect every conversation, not just the one the changes are being made in.

Any ideas/solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your Web Chat code? I think all of your users are sharing the same conversation and user state. Take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697967/10708483)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tdurnford you are right. I had been checking just for the users name, but as the issue you linked said it seems that it is the users id is what the bot needs to distinguish between multiple users. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!